When using autofac multitenant, how can we inject a tenant-scoped service in an AuthenticationHandler
We are trying to implement multitenancy in a .Net Core 8 application, using the Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant package.
We identify tenants based on HTTP headers set by a reverse proxy.
We have separate databases per tenant.
We have a custom AuthenticationHandler, which needs to access data in the tenant database. But I cannot inject tenant scoped services in the handler?
Based on setting breakpoints, I can see that the AuthenticationHandler is called before our ITenantIdentificationStrategy implementation is called?
How do I get my tenant resolved before instantiating the AuthenticationHandler? Or, alternatively, make tenant-scoped servces accessible inside the HandleAuthenticateAsync in the handler (e.g through HttpContext.RequestServices)?

There's not enough info here (eg, your startup, any repro) to answer this. However, the point of that multi tenant package is to set up request services properly at the start of a request, so my guess is you don't have the Startup class set up right. I can't quantify that or provide any other guess because there's not enough here.

Thanks - this is unfortunately part of a larger project, which I am not allowed to share. I will to to make a small reproducer.
